# How to set path on mac of android sdk?

Tags: android, macos

I have downloaded **adt-bundle-mac-x86_64** in that bundle. There is an eclipse and sdk folder .I put the **adt-bundle-mac-x86_64** on **application** tab of my mac machine. I opened eclipse and clicked window ->android sdk manager -->install managers. I installed all sdk manager as show in image .[image]

But my issue is that when I go to property -->Android I will not see any sdk (please check the image)
[image]

so I check the path on terminal. It display this 
Last login: Mon Sep  1 05:24:21 on ttys000
localhost:~ naveenkumar$ echo $PATH
**

```
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/Development/adt-bundle/sdk/platform-tools:/Development/adt-bundle/sdk/tools
localhost:~ naveenkumar$
```

** 
I also check on platform folder it have all android 7-20.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Go to Eclipse -> preferences -> Android
There you can specify path of you SDK location

It will look like this
[image]

EDIT:
You should run a software update in Eclipse (Help > Check for Updates) and update the ADT.

Comment: eclise i don't have option

Comment: what should be my sdk path ?

Comment: Look at the picture, may be it will help

Comment: already found but what is my sdk path ?please check my update and image

Comment: sdk folder where adt bundle was downloaded for example: 
/Users/abc/Downloads/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140624/sdk <br/>

Comment: Looking from pic you posted it is : /Applications/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64/sdk  for you